# calculate the sum of values in ng repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angularjs. I am displaying list of items using ng-repeat. how to calculate the sum of it? is there any simple method to calculate it in html using expression?

```
name  numberofyears amount interest 
 xxx       2          4000   4%
 yyy       3          3000   10%
 zzz       5          6000    6%

 Total     10        13000   16%
```

First three rows are from ng repeat.I just want to calculate the total as shown above. Thanks in advance

This is pretty similar to [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat) this question. But not exactly. I am trying to calculate using expression since i have many rows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating sum of repeated elements in AngularJS ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Comment: [Other post on sum of values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23842979/1959948)

Comment: Ya i saw that. Is it possible to calculate in html itself rather than going to controller. I have around 9 columns its taking long time @Dalorzo

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CHBm8RCqW5RNZWrzAe5r?p=preview

Comment: `I am trying to calculate using expression` what do you mean?

Comment: @dfsq I mean in html. Some thing like this {{}} in final tr. I am asking whether we can calculate using $index or some other. Sorry if its a silly question

Comment: You can build custom directive for that.

Answer (score 18):

It is possible to do it, but I think this kind of logic is best suited for your controller. Anyhow this is a possible way of achieving what you asked for using ng-init:

```
 <table ng-init="items.total = {}">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>numberofyears</td>
      <td>amount</td>
      <td>intrest</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td ng-init="items.total.numberofyears = items.total.numberofyears + item.numberofyears">{{item.numberofyears}}</td>
      <td ng-init="items.total.amount = items.total.amount + item.amount">{{item.amount}}</td>
      <td ng-init="items.total.interest = items.total.interest + item.interest">{{item.interest}}%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>{{items.total.numberofyears}}</td>
      <td>{{items.total.amount}}</td>
      <td>{{items.total.interest}}%</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: @wawy I have tried this, it is showing items.total as empty array. it is not storing data into it. could you please help. and i am not getting any errors too

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mention - you would sum in your controller and display the summed value after your ng-repeat.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection.

So, ng-repeat is for rendering and would not be the place for business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have around 9 columns and around 50 data from Db. I have to call function to controller each time for every column eh?

Comment: Yes, you loop through each item and sum up the values you want. e.g. in your controller `$scope.total = mySum;` then you just add an extra row below your ng-repeat to display the totals. There are good libraries out there like lodash that can help make summing the data pretty simple e.g. `$scope.mySum = _.reduce(myArray, function(sum, myRecord) {
  return sum + myRecord.amount;
});` http://lodash.com/docs#reduce

Comment: I don't like this solution, with a lot of data it's expensive, imagine with an old smartphone. But ng-repeat is not better. Maybe you should sum on server side when you get your data.

Comment: You don't have to use a client side controller :) - anyway, the _best_ location to sum the data is the database but we don't have that context given the OPs question. This could also be nicely handled via server-rendering for hand-held devices.

Answer (score 1):

Do the Math in controller, then you can add `<tr ng-if="$last"> </tr>` In `ng-repeat` and show the final result

controller e.x - simple one

```
function sum (object) {
    var data = object;
    var tmpSum

     for (var i in object){
      tmpSum =+ object[i].value;
    }

    $scope.sum = tmpSum 
};
```

view e.x

`<tr ng-if="$last">{{sum}} </tr>`