# Sum of ng-repeat values in table row-wise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am new to angularjs, and trying to populate the table with values (integer values) using ng-repeat, the values are correctly populating in the table using input variable id=v1, but i am unable to put sum of the row to the label which is in the last column of table, please help/ guide.

Html Code:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-controller="Dataload" ng-model="orderProp"  ng-repeat="(key, value) in Dataloads | groupBy:'project'">
<td>
<label id="projectname" name="projectname" readonly style="width:300px">{{key}}</label>
</td>
<td ng-repeat="Dataload in value | orderBy:'date':false ">
<div>
<select ID="DropDownList1" Width="8%" Height="28px">                                                                        
<option value="pending">&#9994;</option>
<option value="accept">&#9989;</option>
<option value="reject">&#10060;</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="v1" name="" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" data-ng-model="Dataload.qty" required />
</div>
</td>
<td>
<label style="width:90px" name="total" id="total" >**want to show sum of row in this label**</label>
</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
```

Controller Code:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("GMAO3App");
app.controller('Dataload', Dataload);
Dataload.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'ngAuthSettings'];
function Dataload($scope, $rootScope, $http, ngAuthSettings) {

    var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;
    $http.get(ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + 'web/partes/Dataload?worker=233&society=1&branch=0&start=2017-05-29&end=2017-06-04').
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.Dataloads = data;
          var Data_project = [];
          var Data1_qty = [];
          var Data2_date = [];
          for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.Dataloads.length; i++) {
              Data_project[i] = $scope.Dataloads[i].project;
              Data1_qty[i] = $scope.Dataloads[i].qty;
              Data2_date[i] = $scope.Dataloads[i].date;
          }

      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("error");
      });

};
```

Sample Image:
[Image contains the UI and sample data for example (1,6,1 2,3), i want to add these values and add their sum to last column of row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFuOR.jpg)

Comment: Can you not get the length of the array to display in the variable?

Comment: Please post sample data also

Comment: @Sai i have edited the ques and attached my GUI with sample data.

Comment: @Y.Hewa i am putting values from controller directly using ng-repeat

Comment: so basically you want the sum of the DataLoad.qty for each row?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646125/calculate-the-sum-of-values-in-ng-repeat-angularjs 

is this what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Y.Hewa yes i want sum of DataLoad.qty for each row  in the last column

Comment: could you paste the rest of your <tbody>

Comment: and it's not fully similar but somehow similar still not working, i had tried it.

Comment: @Y.Hewa i have updated code.

Comment: can you try this ? <label style="width:90px" name="total" id="total" >{{value | map:'qty' | sum}}</label>

Comment: @Jenny thanks this solved my problem, i was finding exact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label style="width:90px" name="total" id="total" >{{value | map:'qty' | sum}}
</label>
```

This solved my problem. Thanks to @Jenny

Answer (score 0):

You can access the DataLoads lentgh to get the number of rows that display at the end, outside the ng-repeat.

```
<td>
     <label style="width:90px" name="total" id="total">{{DataLoads.length}}</label>
</td>
```

## **EDITED**

Try it this way :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
         <tr ng-controller="Dataload" ng-model="orderProp"  ng-repeat="(key, value) in Dataloads | groupBy:'project'">
             <td>
                 <label id="projectname" name="projectname" readonly style="width:300px">{{key}}</label>
             </td>
             <td ng-repeat="Dataload in value | orderBy:'date':false" ng-init="items.total = {}">
             <div>
                <select ID="DropDownList1" Width="8%" Height="28px">                                                                        
                   <option value="pending">&#9994;</option>
                   <option value="accept">&#9989;</option>
                   <option value="reject">&#10060;</option>
                </select>
              <input type="text" id="v1" name="" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" data-ng-model="Dataload.qty" ng-init="items.total.qty = items.total.qty + Dataload.qty" required />
             </div>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <label style="width:90px" name="total" id="total" >{{items.total.qty}}</label>
             </td>

         </tr>
    </tbody>
    <table>
```

Comment: I want to add the whole row and put their sum in last column while using ng-repeat, i have updated my question and attached sample data and GUI, please re-check.

Comment: I have updated it but i am getting the sum of all of the rows in every last column; in case of data set i have given above in my post, it is giving 41 at the end of both rows, instead of giving sum of single row it's calculating sum of all rows puts that value in the end of every row as total.

Comment: @MachineGuy try putting the 'ng-init="items.total = {}" ' in the first <tr> instead of the <table>

Comment: I have got solution, by @Jenny help in upper comments, it's very easy solution, still thanks for your help.