# Getting total of a row Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a simple row that I am trying to display the total of.
In my html I have

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td ng-init="iTotal= iTotal + item.price">{{item.price}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total :</td>
        <td>Total:{{iTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
```

In my controller I have

```
var vm=this;
vm.Itotal=0;
```

This basically doesn't gives me blank for iTotal no error. 
Please let me know how to fix it to get the result. Thanks

Comment: Did you get item.price in your page?

Comment: items is an array in your controller, so why can't you just perform that operation in your controller, assign the result to a scope variable and display it?

Comment: yeah I got the item.price right. I get all values right just the iTotal is not showing anything

Comment: as I mentioned before, the correct way here is to perform your operation in the controller, and display it after.

Comment: create a fiddle please.

Comment: you could use a custom filter as mentioned in below post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842979/angularjs-sum-of-rows-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using view model annotation:

```
var vm=this;
vm.Itotal=0;
```

Then you should access `vm.Itotal` like this:

```
<td ng-init="controller.Itotal = controller.Itotal + item.price">{{item.price}}</td>
```

Pay attention that you use `iTotal` in your view and `Itotal` (I in uppercase) in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple way:
[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ARb0F1D80QFzO5HNa3df?p=info)

**HTML:**

```
   <table>
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td >{{item.price}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total:{{iTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
   $scope.items=[{
       "id": 1,
       "price": 12,
   },
   {
       "id": 1,
       "price": 1,
    }];
    $scope.iTotal=0;
    $scope.items.forEach(function(i){
        $scope.iTotal= $scope.iTotal + i.price;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle explaining the same: (Not created by me, Copied from JSFiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/J9Aj8/

```
angular.module("app", []).
   filter("sum", function sum$$factory() {
   return function sum$$filter(collection) {
     var sum = 0;
  _.forOwn(collection, function(value) {
      switch (typeof value) {
       case 'number': sum += value; break;
       case 'string': sum += (value >>> 0); break;
       default: // don't know what to do with this, maybe something else!
       break;
     }
  });
  return sum;
};
}).
controller("itemsCtrl", function() {
  var self = this;
  this.model = {};
  this.numbers = [
    36,
    72,
    80,
    101,
    9,
    42
  ];
  this.addNumber = function() {
    var value = self.model.newNumber;
    if (value === value && typeof value === 'number') {
      self.numbers.push(value);
      self.model.newNumber = NaN;            
    }
  };
});
```