# How to make calculations with ng-repeat data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm pretty brand new to Angular so please bear with me.  I am trying to make a calculation of a main "total budget" value minus the sum of other values displayed.

My index.html is currently:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Destination</th>         
      <th>Total Budget</th>
      <th>Hotel Cost</th>
      <th>Airfare Cost</th>
      <th>Miscellaneous</th>
      <th>Budget Remaining</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="trip.destination"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="trip.budget"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="trip.lodgingCost"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="trip.airfareCost"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="trip.miscCost"></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTrip()">Add Trip</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="update()">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="trip in trips">
      <td>{{trip.destination}}</td>
      <td>{{trip.budget}}</td>
      <td>{{trip.lodgingCost}}</td>
      <td>{{trip.airfareCost}}</td>
      <td>{{trip.miscCost}}</td>
      <td>{{ getRemaining() }}</td> <<!--here is where I run the calculation -->

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my controller.js, I've tried variations of some of the things I have found on stackoverflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842979/angularjs-sum-of-rows-ng-repeat), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646125/calculate-the-sum-of-values-in-ng-repeat-angularjs), but I've mostly been getting undefined and NaN's, as if the actual value isn't being read properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show the controller with `getRemaining` function

Comment: is getRemaining making a http request? If it is the page would load with undefine because the data is still being process by the http in your controller

Comment: I've not much in that, because nothing I have tried has worked, so I've been deleting code when it's not playing nice.  But, here is my last try:  `$scope.getRemaining = function(){
 var remainder =  $scope.trip.budget - ( $scope.trip.airfareCost + $scope.trip.lodgingCost + $scope.trip.miscCost);
 return remainder;
}`

Comment: Just return a static number in getRemaining function and ensure it's working. If it's working the issue might be in the calculation

Answer (score 1):

You may try it without the help of a controller function since it is a basic calculation. Though this method is not recommended, its good to get you started.

You can try replacing `<td>{{ getRemaining() }}</td>` with this:

```
<td>{{ trip.budget - (trip.lodgingCost + trip.airfareCost + trip.miscCost) }}</td>
```

This is a simple arithmetic calculation, and it will give you the desired result **if all things in this expression are numbers**. If any of the item in that expression is `NaN`, the result will be `NaN`. So you need to take care of that.

**Update**:

As per the comment, the data is in wrong format. You are expecting numbers for arithmetic calculation, but they are actually strings. So a calculation like this

```
"1500" - ("700" + "500" + "200")
```

will result in a large negative number like `-700498700` because the arithmetic is being done after string concatenation i.e. the actual operation is `1500 - 700500200` which results in `-700498700`.

Temporarily, to make your UI work, you can try a trick. Change the expression to this:

```
<td>{{ (+trip.budget) - ((+trip.lodgingCost) + (+trip.airfareCost) + (+trip.miscCost)) }}</td>
```

This will manually typecast the strings to numbers. But the actual fix should be done on MongoDB so that it returns the numbers.

Comment: Well, this has gotten me closer than I was!  Your code as-is pasted into my code yielded a substantially large negative number.  Playing with the code, it works when it's just the budget minus one of the budget items, but seems to break when parentheses are introduced.

Comment: It is impossible to be broken. Can you show me the values of these items (`trip.budget, trip.lodgingCost, trip.airfareCost, trip.miscCost`)?

Comment: Values are being pulled from MongoDB: `{
"_id": "596ec5ed01bca5eebd78fbd0",
"destination": "Los Angeles",
"budget": "1500",
"lodgingCost": "700",
"airfareCost": "500",
"miscCost": "200"
},
{
"_id": "596ec5ed01bca5eebd78fbd1",
"destination": "New York",
"budget": "1600",
"lodgingCost": "800",
"airfareCost": "500",
"miscCost": "100"
},
{
"_id": "596ec939fcaff20544d8e18d",
"destination": "Japan",
"budget": "4000",
"lodgingCost": "1500",
"airfareCost": "2000",
"miscCost": "300"
}`

Comment: @tardisdriver -- See, there is something wrong with the data. The values are strings, and not numbers (see the quotes around the numbers, those make them strings).

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right.  Silly mistake.  It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the trip object as a parameter to your getRemaining() function.

```
<td>{{ getRemaining(trip) }}</td>
```

In your controller, use this object to get values for calculation instead of $scope.trip. So your function would be,

```
$scope.getRemaining = function(trip){ 
    var remainder = trip.budget - ( trip.airfareCost + trip.lodgingCost + trip.miscCost); 
    return remainder; 
}
```